# Android : Why NUMBER_KEY return the number in reverse order

Tags: android

I am trying to read the contact list using the following code:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(People.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

while (cur.moveToNext()) 
{ 
   String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People._ID));
       Cursor personCur = cr.query(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI, 
                null, 
                Contacts.Phones.PERSON_ID +"= ?"+                                     Contacts.Phones.NUMBER_KEY , 
                    new String[]{id}, null);

            String phoneKey = "";
            while (personCur.moveToNext()) {
                phoneKey = personCur.getString(personCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.NUMBER_KEY));

            }
```

The problem is that phoneKey return in reverse order meaning if the phone number is 054-123-4567 the value is 7654321450

I could not find any documentation on this issue.
Any idea how to fix it? or is it the expected result?

thanks
-Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, Contacts.Phones.NUMBER_KEY is deprecated. 
Secondly, why do you need this value? This is not the phone number, but the "normalized" phone number.
If you want the phone number in the way you have your code, use Contacts.Phones.NUMBER

Anyways, I would suggest you not to use deprecated elements unless you are targeting older phones.

================

Phone numbers are stored in stripped reversed order for easier matching. It helps to use the LIKE operator in SQL.

For a normal SQL user, it might look same to use where NUMBER_KEY LIKE '%1234' and where NUMBER_KEY LIKE '4321%'.
But for the db engine, having the wildcard at the end is much easier (efficient) Efficiency is a major factor for incoming call caller id lookup.

BTW, you might have not noticed, most phones (not talking about android only) does not match the whole number for caller id lookup.
In all my Nokia phones I have a number saved, say its 016 12345678 (its not the real number) as Mr X
When I get phone call from another number 016 99345678, it shows Mr X is calling. It compares only last few digits!!!